# total spin (J-resolved) projected band structure with SOC

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, plane-waves

I have been asked by a colleague if it is possible to calculate the spin-projected band structure (with SOC) for a material he is studying. He referenced a paper [Boschini et al. Sci. Reports 2015 - open access](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep15304). In this paper the authors show (Fig 4e) the band structure for Bi2Te3 with the j=1/2, 3/2 character of the band structure along the X-Gamma-L line.

Is it possible to do something similar using Wien2K or another plane wave code?

In particular, I would like to show the projected J character with SOC for a similar, but different material. The authors used a KKR Green's function code. I would like to use a plane wave code if possible. Thanks for any advice you can offer.